# How add style="background-image in element div using asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the folder `assets/images/default/user` I stored an image `banner.png`.

How can I add this image direct in the following `background-image`?

```
<div class="banner-img" style="background-image: url('/assets/default/users/banner.png');"></div>
```

Comment: or this one `url(<%= asset_path 'banner.png' %>)`

Comment: thank you. Now fine with url(<%= asset_path 'banner.png' %>)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails Assets: [Rails Assets Doc.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

```
asset-url("rails.png") becomes url(/assets/rails.png)
asset-path("rails.png") becomes "/assets/rails.png"
```

In your case supposed to be like this:

```
url(<%= asset_path 'banner.png' %>)
```