# Don't show background images on Heroku. But local is working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, background-image

My tag:

```
= link_to '', root_path, class: 'items__footage'
```

My selector:

```
.items__footage {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: url('/assets/footage_still.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

The path of my image is `assets/images/footage_still.png`. If I indicate this path, my image does not work locally.

I have done `rake assets:precompile`. But it did not help.

Comment: Is this a `css` or `sass` file?

Comment: application.css.scss

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390777/how-add-style-background-image-in-element-div-using-asset-pipeline/36391043#36391043

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can use ruby code in your css file then use items_footage's background like this.

```
background: url("<%= asset_path('footage_still.png') %>");
```

To use ruby code inside css file make that file as `filename.css.erb`

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production)

> In the production environment Sprockets uses the fingerprinting scheme
>   outlined above. By default Rails assumes assets have been precompiled
>   and will be served as static assets by your web server.
>
> During the precompilation phase an SHA256 is generated from the
>   contents of the compiled files, and inserted into the filenames as
>   they are written to disk. These fingerprinted names are used by the
>   Rails helpers in place of the manifest name.

So, in production all your assets will be precompiled and will be served from `public/assets`. Also the file will be renamed with a fingerprint. So actually In production your file name will look something like

```
footage_still-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.png
```

The fingerprint will changes every time the file content changes and is useful for caching the static assets, generally called `cache busting`.
So when you hard code the image url `/assets/footage_still.png`, it will break in production. To handle the situation, rails provides something called [asset url helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html). 
To make it work, you have to rename your `.css` file to `.scss` if not and change.

```
background: url('/assets/footage_still.png') no-repeat;
```

to

```
background: image_url('footage_still.png') no-repeat;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `image_url('footage_still.png')` and let rails find the path of the image

Comment: This image must changes to another image when :hover action. Therefore I do this via background image.