# How to add a background image using an absolute path in markup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

So I am using pdfkit gem, to make a pdf. The following is the typical syntax to make it work

`<%= image_tag("#{Rails.root}/public/images/signature-white.png", class: "signature", alt: "signature")%>`

It requires us to give the absolute paths of where the images, also the images are to be in `public`

Now I have to add a background image dynamically in the markup

I came up with this

```
<div style="background-image: url('/images/background.png')">
</div>
```

This is fine, if it had been a web page. However this pdfkit requires the path to be absolute, and I am clueless about how to use the url helper to access the image in `public/images/background.png` using absolute path

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390777/how-add-style-background-image-in-element-div-using-asset-pipeline/36391043#36391043

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `file` scheme as in `file:///home/gregnavis/images/background.png`.

Comment: hey this works, but is there any way like a keyword to get this dynamically, because in production I would have to change this right?