# Rails Image_Tag not Accessing Images in other Directories

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

As of day three of trying to get this to work, I'm wondering if there are special rules involving the image_tag and how it works in a rails context. My rails html tag is as follows on the application.html.erb in the layout directory. I will get to the paths in a minute.

```
<%=image_tag('./app/assets/images/leaf.jpg')%>
```

The directory path of the image is:

```
app/assets/images/leaf.jpg
```

The directory path of the file is:

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

I'm thinking that views is within app and just has to get back out of layouts to 
access app/assets/images....etc.

Comment: the asset pipeline already expects the path to an image to be "app/assets/images" so you just need to tell it where to go from there "leaf.jpg" in your case.

Comment: check this link => https://stackoverflow.com/q/36390777/2325924

Comment: Thanks, I will update here when not in an Apex hole.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this, in regular views, you can access images in the `app/assets/images` directory like this:

```
<%= image_tag('leaf.jpg') %>
```

See the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) what say about asset pipeline.

**CSS and ERB**

The asset pipeline automatically evaluates ERB. This means if you add an `erb` extension to a CSS asset (for example, `application.css.erb`), then helpers like `asset_path` are available in your CSS rules:

```
.class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'leaf.jpg' %>) }
```